# Use Mathematical Induction to verify that, for n ≥ 1, P(n) = n(n + 1)(n + 2)(n + 3) is divisible by 24.

Tags: logic, induction, solution-verification

The first step I have proved 24|P(1)

In the second step, I have assumed 24|P(k) i.e P(k)= 24r (r is an integer)

In the third step, I should prove 24|P(k+1)
So I have followed some steps for proving it.
$P(k+1) = (k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)$
$= k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3) + 4(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)$
$= 24r + 4(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)$(since assumption in step 2)
$= 24r + 4(6m)$ (in  this step I applied theory that product of three consecutive integers divisible by factorial 3)
$= 24(r+m)$ ,which is 24|P(k+1)

My problem is can I directly apply the theory that the product of three consecutive integers divisible by factorial 3 in the induction step without proving it?

Comment: If you want to, you can quickly prove it as a side-note or lemma... or if you had seen it proved already in lecture, in the book, or as an earlier homework exercise you can skip it here.  Write your proofs with your audience in mind.

Comment: You can if you want to, just prove it separately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prove by induction that $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ is an integer multiple of $24$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632245/prove-by-induction-that-nn1n2n3-is-an-integer-multiple-of-24)

Comment: "My problem is can I directly apply the theory that the product of three consecutive integers divisible by factorial 3 in the induction step without proving it?"  I'd say no because in essence that is what you are trying to prove (but for four consecutive numbers).... but... it's really the job of the question writer to clarify you cant.  (You can, as suggest, prove it separately.)

Comment: By the way, it's conventional in induction proofs that $P(n)$ refers to a *statement* about $n$ that is true or false.  That is $P(n)$ "equals" the statement  $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$.  It's not that $P(n)$ is equal to be value $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$.  Then again.... I don't know how the question was asked.

Comment: Without induction: $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) = 24 \binom{n+3}{4} $

Answer (score 1):

Well, with three consecutive numbers, you know that at least of them is even (hence it is divisible by $2$), and at least one of them is divisible by $3$ (and another one of them will have a remainder of $1$ when divided by $3$, and the third one will have a remainder of $2$ when divided by $3$)

So, we know the product of those three numbers is divisible by $2 \cdot 3 = 6$

But note!  You can of course use this very same kind of argument that the product of $4$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $24$: since one of these numbers is divisible by $4$, and one of the others is even as well, we know it is divisible by $8$, and again at least one of them will be divisible by $3$, and so it is divisible by $3 \cdot 8 = 24$

So ... to maybe keep in the spirit of induction, maybe you should prove that the product of three consecutive numbers is divisble by $6$ using induction as well :P

Comment: Thank you very much!